# Coughing captured in writing

Tags: onomatopoeia

My native language is German and although many people find German to sound like a coughing fit, the language totally lacks an onomatopoeia for coughing (real coughing).
Nor can I think of one in English.

- Is there an onomatopoeia for coughing?
- If not, how can I capture it in writing?

Comment: *"What do you"--cough, cough--"want for breakfast?"* . . . You can also examine the novels of your favorite English writers to see how they do it in their prose. You could also pose your question on a writing forum for possible techniques.

Comment: I think this is either Off Topic *writing advice*, or Primarily Opinion-based. The only "onomatopoeic" English word is probably ***ahem***, but obviously that's for the attention-getting "non-verbal communication device". We don't have one that captures the essence of *"Cough it up! It's only a lung!"*

Comment: @FumbleFingers... not necessarily. My first question has a clear answer so it seems (no, there isn't one). As for the second one... depending on what the sound is there might be a commonly accepted term. I recently learned "sad trombone" to be one of those. I was wondering, if there was something similar for coughing. The fact that you think it is opinion based hints at that there isn't a common way, so this would be a fine answer to the second part. In essence it's "No and you cannot". I don't see why this would be close worthy

Comment: @Emanuel: The way I look at it is (1) - it's General Reference that English doesn't have a standard onomatopoeic representation for "real coughing" (just as we don't have one for "blowing one's nose"). And (2) - in the absence of a "standard" form, asking ELU how to represent it in writing is effectively POB ***writing advice***. Now if you'd asked *why* there's no "coughing" equivalent to *sneeze = **atishoo***, that would be a different question (not one that I'd know the answer to, I'm afraid! :)

Answer (score 8):

*Cough* **is** onomatopoeic. [***OED 1***](http://archive.org/stream/oed02arch#page/1048/mode/2up), *s.v.* **Cough**, *v.*, recites Dutch and German cognates and remarks that “All these words appear to be of echoic origin, representing various sounds and actions made with the breath.”

Comment: It is, but examples like "to sneeze" and "to giggle" show that there my be a verb and still a second, imitation-only word as well (atchoo, hehe).

Comment: It was more onomatopoeic when *gh* was pronounced /x/.

Answer (score 3):

I would just simply use the word cough or maybe cough with an asterisk on each side.  You could use *ahem* too but I think you would lose your readers, or at least make them think too much about a simple cough.

Answer (score 2):

A little descriptive language *instead of* or *along with* an onomatopoeic representation could be a solution:

> Example 1: **"Chelsea started to speak, 'I was out ill *kaff! kaff!* last week.' adding the cough for affect."**

or

> Example 2: **"George savored the flavor of the cherry candy until he aspirated his own saliva and started to cough and choke, thinking it ironic that he would asphyxiate on a candy called a *Lifesaver*."**

And...for more ideas, search for lists of onomatopoeic words like [this one](http://kathytemean.wordpress.com/2009/12/29/onomatopoeia-word-list/).

Answer (score 2):

Onomatopoeia for coughing which I read in Sandman is

**""Khoff Khak Khak!!""**

Comics is I believe is a genuine source for onomatopoeic references.

[Sandman](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Sandman_%28Vertigo%29) are comics by DC. Written by Neil Gaiman. A very effective writer.

Other book written by **Neil Gaiman**

**American Gods**

Comment: Not my downvote, sorry. Perhaps the user believes that comics are not a sufficiently authoritative source. (Just guessing here!)

Answer (score 1):

And while it is not exactly in response to your question, I cannot resist the sound of a person vomiting, as written by Ian M. Banks in "Against A Dark Background":

> Bleurghch! Aauuilleurch! Hooowwerchresst-t-t!