# Is there an onomatopoeia for coughing up blood?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm writing a short story for my EAL Class and I was thinking of an onomatopoeia
for coughing up blood. I tried all the words I knew but nothing felt quite right.
Is there a proper English word that I can use to express this action?

Comment: -- **Khoff! Khak!!** -- *there was blood*!
Not sure of a single word though!

Comment: It's spelled _onomatopoeia_ and pronounced /anəmatə'poyə/, btw.

Comment: Coughing is already one ;)

Comment: Related (without explicit blood though): http://english.stackexchange.com/q/161307/42179

Comment: I'm pretty sure the sound of coughing up blood is very close to identical to general coughing. So there could be no special onomatopoeia.

Comment: Not what you asked for but here goes anyway... since as was already pointed out, coughing up phlegm and coughing up blood sound very similar, you may want to instead, make someone ***witnessing*** the blood-coughing have a strong reaction to the scene.

Comment: @KristinaLopez how does one find an onomatopoeia for witnessing coughing blood?

Comment: @Aoki, I prefaced my comment with "Not what you asked for...." but let's use our imagination anyway! :-)  How about this? 
***"Blech! <kakk!> Glurg!" John violently heaved at the sight of his friend's coughed-up blood splashing across the tile floor, instantly coagulating into dark-red domed puddles.***

Comment: @JohnLawler: /oya/? Not the pronunciation I've ever used :) I think /iya/'s much more common.

Comment: It's _poeia_ in Greek, and all four vowels are pronounced. Since it's a borrowing, you can pronounce it any way you want. But since it's a fancy word with a meaning associated with sound, its pronunciation is more important than that of most words.

Comment: @KristinaLopez "*instantly* coagulating"? Not a doctor, are we? (I'm just teasing.)

Comment: Not so much an onomatopoeia as it it is visually appealing: "I asked for my handkerchief back but I declined it once I realized he had *ragged* all over it." (as in, [*on the rag*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/rag))

Answer (score 1):

"Is there an onomatopoeia for coughing up blood?"

> No. There is no word that would resemble or simulate the sound of coughing up blood specifically. It wouldn't make sense to have one anymore than it would to have a sizzling sound or hissing sound specifically for the frying of a skirt steak versus chicken.

But, is there a word that resembles, simulates, or is associated with any sound that would resemble 'coughing up blood', like coughing up syrup, baby formula, or hot wax? Maybe something that starts with 'gla', or 'ghluh', but they kind of sound weird to me. Go with your gut on that one I guess.

Answer (score 0):

[Hemoptysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hemoptysis) is the medical term for coughing up blood. It is a noun though, so maybe no use to you if you're interested in a verb.